# Convert time string to Unix time date of the same day

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, foundation

how to convert a string hour to millisecond of the day?

for exemple:

```
let strDate = "06:00 PM"
```

Or:

```
let strDate = "09:00 AM"
```

my code:

```
let dateString = "06:00 PM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
else { fatalError() }
print(date)
```

for example my string is: 06:00 PM, so I want to have the date in millisecond of today Thursday 20 September 2018 at 06:00 PM

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry but this site it is not a code writing service. Edit your question and post what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Edited..........

Comment: your date format it is wrong HH is for 24h format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your DateFormatter default date to startOfDay for today, set the formatter locale locale to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing your time then you can simply get your resulting date timeIntervalSince1970 and multiply by 1000:

```
let strTime = "06:00 PM"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
if let date = formatter.date(from: strTime) {
    let milliseconds = date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    print(milliseconds) // 1537477200000
    let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: milliseconds/1000)
    print(date2.description(with: .current))  // Thursday, September 20, 2018 at 6:00:00 PM Brasilia Standard Time
}
```

Comment: That would include the current seconds/nanoseconds in the difference. Better set `formatter.defaultDate` to the *start* of the current day (as I mentioned above).

Comment: There is a problem with the time zone, where I find it returns to me the resulta at 03:00 PM instead of 06:00 PM, why?

Comment: @mickael you need to print the date description with locale. If you want 6pm UTC time you need to set the formatter timezone to zeroSecondsFromGMT

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to parse the date string:

```
let dateString = "06:00 PM"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.defaultDate = Date()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Then, you need to get the start of day:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let start = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
```

After that, get the time interval between `date` and `start`:

```
let timeInterval = date.timeIntervalSince(start)
let milliseconds = timeInterval * 1000.0
```

Comment: This is not good maybe you did not understand, for example my string is: 06:00 PM, so I want to have the date in millisecond of today Thursday 20 September 2018 at 06:00 PM

Comment: @mickael you mean unix epoch time for Thursday 20 September 2018 at 06:00 PM local time ?

Comment: @mickael The date is not included in the input string. Do you want to assume today?

Comment: @Sweeper if you don't set your date formatter locale to en_US_POSIX this might fail if the user locale/settings it is set to 24h

Comment: @LeoDabus It's always the locales that get me. Edited.